# Limit Ubuntu-SSH Image Container's Disk Size

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, virtual-machine

**How can I limit the storage use of a Ubuntu 20.04 Image Container with SSH Enabled in Docker?**

*I understand that one should not use Docker as a VM Technology but this is only for educational purposes*

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  ubuntu-vm:
    build: .
    image: ubuntu-ssh
    ports:
      - "2222:22"
    environment:
      - ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    restart: always
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.24.0.2

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.24.0.0/16
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openssh-server && \
    mkdir /var/run/sshd

RUN echo 'root:password' | chpasswd

RUN sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

EXPOSE 22

CMD [ "/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D", "-e" ]
```

**I have tried** adding `storage_opt: size: 100G` to the compose file, but upon doing df -H in the container, it returned the host disk available size and disk usage (in this example 400gb used, 1.9tb available)

Will I have to create a disk in my host and map it my container's /dev/sdx disk? Or is there a better way to do it where the container does have access to the host disk as full but a chunk of it.

Comment: `but upon doing df -H` ? But what happens when you try to create data with more than 100G storage?

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried adding storage_opt: size: 100G to the compose file, but upon doing df -H in the container, it returned the host disk available size and disk usage (in this example 400gb used, 1.9tb available)

Sure, because `df -h` will show the size of the *device*, not available quota limits on specific filesystem. Create a file bigger than `100G` to check.

```
$ docker run -ti --rm --storage-opt size=5G alpine
# dd if=/dev/random of=file bs=10M count=1023
dd: error writing 'file': Quota exceeded
512+0 records in
511+0 records out
```

This is most probably docker storage driver specific - I tested on btrfs.

Comment: Sure that works but I do not want the container to be able to see the total disk size, but only what is allocated to them (100gb)

Comment: `I do not want the container to be able to see the total disk size` Then I think `Will I have to create a disk in my host` yes, and you will have to configure dockerd  to store data there. Leave the question open and maybe someone else will have a solution, or ask a separate question not about the limit, but about virtualizing of the disc. For disc virtualization, full virtualization sounds like a better way. I do not think overlayfs can override upper file system size - consider researching how docker storage drivers actually work.

Comment: yes upon i did come across docker device mapper device driver, which allows for setting base disk size but unfortunately they advise not to use it for production and that it's support will be removed soon so i will try to figure out how to go on about virtualizing the disk